# Ruby GraphViz DOT Incorrectly Rendering PNGs

Tags: ruby, graphviz, dot

I'm making a small program to render some images of binary trees for a class. I want the program to automatically make a bunch of .dot and .png files for me, but the line to render the .png's isn't working unless I manually call it. The trouble code:

```
@file_num = 0

data.each do |x|
    @tree.add(x)
    draw_frame(@tree, @filename, @file_num)
    @file_num += 1
end


(0...(data.length)).each do |x|
    `dot -Tpng #{@filename}#{x}.dot > #{x}.png`
end
```

When I walk the tree, it makes the .dot files (with the draw frame method, I'm eventually going to make a .gif out of the files). Here, the call to `dot...` with backticks should make the png's, but it doesn't. If I run the exact same code in the command line, though, it works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
`dot -Tpng #{@filename}#{x}.dot -o#{x}.png`
```

This replaces the stdout piping command `>` with a plain argument to dot telling it to write the file itself.

Comment: You know, it turned out to be that I forgot to close the files after I created them.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the [ruby-graphviz](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-graphviz) gem.